# Implementing the verbose option for my shell command

Tags: c, verbose

I am writing a C code for a shell command. A simple command which connects to servers and sends/receives some basic data. I takes different options like -l -z etc

What i want to do is add a -v option for the command for toggling verbosity. For e.g if I give -v option it will print every detail such as "connected to.." , "listening on port " etc.

Now i dont want if/else logic near every printf statement ( i have 100's of them). What i want is a macro/user defined function say new_print which will take the verbosity flag ( 1 if i give -v option) and the string to print.   If the flag is 0 , it wont print the statement.

Can you please provide some examples for the same

Answer (score 3):

You can do your own "re-implementation" of printf using the variable length aruguments format so it will work very similar to printf but also takes your flag, somthing like:

```
void verbPrintf(bool verbosity, const char *format, ...)
{
    // va_list is a special type that allows hanlding of variable
    // length parameter list
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    // If verbosity flag is on then print it
    if (verbosity)
        vfprintf (stdout, format, args);
    else
        // Do nothing
}
```

then just use that to replce your printf's in your code. eg

```
verbPrintf(verbosity, "my verb print %i\n", 5);
```